# flutter display form errors on the bottom of page

Tags: flutter, forms, validation

I'am working on a flutter application where the user clicks on register button and if input has errors i don't wanna show the errors below the `TextFormField`, i've managed to create a form with a `GlobalKey` and added validator and it's working fine but i'm looking to show errors at the end of page not under `TextFormField`, any ideas how to do that ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you include your code-snippet that will reproduce the same issue you are facing?

Comment: Maybe you need to ignore the validator and show a snackbar instead of the result of your validation logic?

Answer (score 0):

you can use visible widget to show your error text on error with a bool val to
validate your textfields.